# Kendo Custom tooltip for chart, returns tooltip's showing as Undefined

Tags: kendo-ui

When using the event which allows us to custom the tooltips for a bar\line chart. The DataItem that is passed to the event is returned as Undefined . So, is there is property which I can be set that allows custom the tooltip, even when their is alot of pionts in a small area. 
    Example: **template: "#= dataItem.employeeName #"**

```
 Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [tooltip.template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-tooltip.template-StringFunction) option:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
     tooltip: {
         visible: true,
         template: "#=employeeName#"
     }
});
```

You shouldn't need to specify `dataItem` before the field name. Also, try checking `data` instead of `dataItem`.

Comment: I declared as  data but still the points are showing as undefined

Comment: to show series name I used below line:
template: '#= data.series.name #'

Answer (score 0):

Try this One:

```
 tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        template: "#= dataItem.title #: #= dataItem.percentage #%"
                    }
```

For me it is working perfect.
Let me know if any issue.